# Amazon Sagemaker JupiterLab Notebook Geopandas and shapely error install

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pip, amazon-sagemaker

I have a notebook on my AWS Sagemaker that yesterday works fine.
Today, without making any changes, i can't import **Geopandas and Shapely**.

When I do `! pip install pandas geopandas shapely fiona rtree boto3 s3fs fsspec polygon-geohasher scipy pygeohash pygeohash awswrangler` works fine, without any error.

But when I try to do the import, this error appears `OSError: Could not find lib geos_c or load any of its variants ['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so'].` I tried on python 3.6 and 3.8, and it's the same

Does anyone know how to fix this? As I said, yesterday it worked perfectly.

Comment: Uninstall, then reinstall those libraries. Also, update all libraries.

pip uninstall geopandas

pip install geopandas